# Test OAuth2 request in rspec test with oauth-plugin gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, oauth-2.0

I use the latest oauth-plugin with Rails 3.1. I want to test my **OAuth2** API controllers with rspec tests. After trying a bunch of things to authorize my request I simply want to stub the **oauthenticate** filter to get rid of any authentication issues. But I still get a *401 Unauthorized* . Why??

users_controller.rb:

```
class UsersController
  oauthenticate

  def update
    <do something>
  end
end
```

users_controller_spec.rb:

```
describe UsersController do
  describe "POST 'update'" do

      before :each do
        controller.stub!(:oauthenticate).and_return true
      end

      it "should be a successful request" do
        post :update,  { "user_id" => "some id" }
        response.should be_ok
     end
end
```

Expected ActionController::TestResponse to have a response code of 200, but got 401.

[Rspec testing for oauth provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5268672/rspec-testing-for-oauth-provider) doesn't help. With cucumber test everything works fine when setting a valid access token *Authorization header*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK I still don't know why *oauthenticate* becomes not stubbed, but I figured out, how to make a authenticated OAuth2 request in RSpec tests. You have to set *oauth.strategies* and *token* parameters of the request object:

```
def prepare_authenticated_access_token_request
   # Create consumer application
   @client_application = Factory.create(:client_application)
   # Create a user who authorized the consumer
   @resource_owner = Factory.create(:user)
   # Create a valid, authorized access token
   token = Oauth2Token.create :user => @resource_owner, :client_application => @client_application
   # Configure the request object so that it is recognized as a OAuth2 request
   request.env["oauth.strategies"] = [:oauth20_token, :token]
   request.env["oauth.token"] = token
 end
```

Answer (score 2):

Similar to Peter's answer, except a bit nicer because it will only stub the method in the context of this spec:

```
before :each do
  OAuth::Controllers::ApplicationControllerMethods::Filter.
    any_instance.stub(:filter).and_return(true)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

your stubbing approach didn't work because oauthenticate is called as soon as the class is loaded, so by the time you stub is the before filter had already been set on the controller.

I found a way around this by redefining the underlying filter method, as follows:

```
before :each do
  OAuth::Controllers::ApplicationControllerMethods::Filter.class_eval do
    def filter(controller)
      return true
    end
  end
end
```

I found this cleaner than having to create oauth tokens and headers, though of course it doesn't test your authentication anymore.